# How can I handle the "Maximum number of emojis reached (50)" error on discord?

Tags: node.js, error-handling, discord.js

So ive been making a command to steal an emoji from a different server, and im just trying to handle errors, but cannot seem to handle this error without it still throwing the error in my console like a madman...

```
DiscordAPIError: Maximum number of emojis reached (50)
```

is there some way to handle this error so it doesn't crash the bot but simply just inform the user that they cannot add any more emojis in their server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do a check on how many emojis the server currently has, nothing harder.

This is just an example, as you did not provide any code so you need to figure out how to work around this.

```js
const serverTier = message.guild.premiumTier;
let maxSize = 50;
if(serverTier == "TIER_1") maxSize = 100
elseif(serverTier == "TIER_2") maxSize = 150
elseif(serverTier == "TIER_3") maxSize = 250
 
if(message.guild.emojis.cache.size >= maxSize) return message.reply("No can do");
```

Using `Guild.premiumTier` you get a response of which tier of server boosting the server is on, which affects the emoji slots. So this way you can count the amount Guild can have emojis and then check if they have that many.